# Get color for each different message sender randomly (like a hash)

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, message

I'm working on an app which (among many other features) gets messages sent to a student from the school administration system of Hungary (ekreta.hu).

I'd like to have profile pictures for the senders of these messages, but the API doesn't provide them, so this is what I came up with: Similar to Gmail, the first letter of their name appears on a randomly colored circle.

My question is: How do I get a color that is random, but unique to each sender? It should behave like a hash, so it would generate the same color from the same input (from the same sender's name).

[Here's an example of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anELl.png)

Comment: Hope [this](https://pub.dev/packages/random_color) will solve your issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out from a JavaScript answer, translated it to Dart.
This generates a hash from the given string and returns a Dart Color.

```
Color stringToColor(String str) {
  int hash = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    hash = str.codeUnitAt(i) + ((hash << 5) - hash);
  }

  String color = '#';

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var value = (hash >> (i * 8)) & 0xFF;
    color += value.toRadixString(16);
  }

  color += "0";
  color = color.substring(0, 7);

  print(color);

  return colorFromHex(color);
}
```

Comment: This works. But what if i want only dark colors on a white background?

Comment: You're probably better off with something like [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_randomcolor) package, specifying the color to be dark, and storing the result.
I couldn't find a way to "seed" the generated color though, so you'll have to store the generated value.

Answer (score 0):

you are probably keeping these messages somewhere like receivedMessages. Let's say receivedMessages is a map with a key of sender and values, then you could give a random color to that sender the first time they send a message, save it as a value to that key, and use the same color after.

```
CircleAvatar( color: (receivedMessages[sender] == null) ? randomColor : receivedMessages[sender][color],  child: Message(), ... other attributes )
```

Comment: Thank you! In the meantime I figured it out with an actual hash, will post the code soon. I think that will be a better way than saving color, although with your method the user could change to color for each sender if they don't like the generated one.